# Launching an application (JProfiler specifically) by its executable using assertj-swing

Tags: java, swing, jprofiler, assertj

I need to automate JProfiler GUI (switching between various tabs, extracting textual data and verifying them). I have been trying to use assertj-swing library. However, JProfiler is launched by an executable and not by class file.

Is there a method in assertj Swing to launch a app by its executable?

Comment: JProfiler has a command line export utility "bin/jpexport" that exports most views to HTML/XML/CSV. Could you use that instead? Scraping the data from the GUI will be very difficult.

Comment: Hi Ingo, Thanks for the suggestion. But our main intention is to test the functionality of GUI.

Comment: Why do you want to test the JProfiler GUI? This is something we do as part of the release. We actually use assertj-swing to do that.

Comment: We are testing the Jprofiler GUI with a proprietary JVM. According to docs, an application can be invoked by assert-swing if you have a class file. However, i find no class file for invoking Jprofiler GUI (please correct me if i am wrong here) and hence i want to know how to launch it by its executable.

Comment: You would have to add bin/jprofiler.jar and all the libraries in the lib directory as well as its subdirectories and invoke com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication.

Comment: That info was of great help. Thanks Ingo. With respect to the message "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.install4j.api.launcher.StartupNotification$Listener" while invoking profiler, I am guessing we have to build and install 'install4j'; I would like to know if there is any simpler work around/alternative i.e., by downloading a jar file (having it including in class path) ?

Comment: You just have to include the jar file .install4j/i4jruntime.jar

Comment: Inclusion of the .jar files did clear all the exception. However, on running the program to invoke Jprofiler, my code exits on encountering 'APPLICATION.start();' statement without any message. 

Snippet of my code:
public static String JC_LAUNCH_CLASS = "com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication";
APPLICATION = ApplicationLauncher.application(JC_LAUNCH_CLASS);
APPLICATION.start();

any insights on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the context to analyze this problem.